# How can I synchronize multiple threads in WP7?

Tags: multithreading, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm new to development on **Windows Phone 7** and *Silverlight* but I do have experience in win32 and threading in general.

Here's my question:

I am trying to "synchronize" the UI thread w/ another thread that seems to be used by the API's of the object that I am working with. In other words, I would like to make sure that before the user dismisses the current XAML page by pressing the back button, the object that I am working with, which is part of the C# class behind the XAML page is deallocated.

The reason for that is that if I have the deallocation code in the **NavigatedFrom** handler, the UI thread may attempt to release the object *WHILE* it is in fact used by the other thread. Therefore, I do have to somehow synchronize the deallocation of this object.

Ideally, when the user presses the back button on the phone, all I do is set a flag "quit" to true to indicate that the user intends to exit. The methods used by the object that are running on another thread, would "see" that this flag is set and then would BeginInvoke*emphasized text* the deallocation code of the object (only because the object has been allocated on the UI thread so I figured it makes sense to deallocate it on the same thread, not knowing its internal workings.) Finally, it would call **NavigationService.GoBack()** to ensure 'orderly' exit.

Unfortunately, I don't see a way of preventing the XAML page to be dismissed when the user presses the back button although I did override the NavigatedFrom and OnBackKeyPress methods. Even though they contain no code at all, the XAML page is dismissed anyway.

Another thing that is interesting and I would appreciate your comments on this, is that I have a timer (**System.Windows.Threading.DispatchTimer**). Would this timer be associated only with the C# class behind a XAML page that defines it? In other words, is there a concept of a "message pump" associated with each XAML pages or is there just one message pump for the UI thread that basically is used by ALL XAML pages ? I am asking this because although I dismiss the XAML page whose C# class defines the timer, it seems to still be running.

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you describe how you think something is "deallocated" in .NET code?  Any clue what this mystery object might be would help to?  Some third party thing?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am talking about the PhotoCamera object. The MSDN example states that it is a good idea to call its Dispose method when done w/ it. I am worried that if the user presses the back button WHILE the PhotoCamera's "CaptureImageAvailable"'s event handler would be reading from the camera buffer (note that this handler seems to be running in a different thread than the UI thread), my code would attempt to deallocate it from the UI thread at the wrong time (while in use) causing my app to crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The reason for that is that if I have the deallocation code in the NavigatedFrom handler, the UI thread may attempt to release the object WHILE it is in fact used by the other thread. Therefore, I do have to somehow synchronize the deallocation of this object.

Not really a problem. If you queue the navigation on the `Dispatcher` as well, you don't get any NullReferenceExceptions.

Simply use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => NavigationService.Navigate(...))` for safe navigation.

> Would this timer be associated only with the C# class behind a XAML page that defines it?

If you by "class" means "ViewModel", then yes, it most definitively should be in the ViewModel.